# Getting a nested list with "" in the outer list

Tags: python, list

After opening and reading an input file, I'm trying to split the input on different characters. This works well, although I seem to be getting a nested list which I don't want.  My list does not look like `[[list]]`, but like `["[list]"]`. What did I do wrong here?

The input looks like this:

```
name1___1 2 3 4 5
5=20=22=10=2=0=0=1=0=1something,something
name2___1 2 3 4
2=30=15=8=4=3=2=0=0=0;
```

The output looks like this:

```
["['name1", '', '', "1 2 3 4 5', 'name2", '', '', "1 2 3 4']"]
```

Here is my code:

```
file = open("file.txt")
input_of_this_file = file.read()
a = input_of_this_file.split("\n")
b = a[0::2] # so i get only the even lines
c = str(b) # to make it a string so the .strip() works
d = c.strip()  # because there were whitespaces
e = d("_")
print e
```

If i then do:

```
x = e[0]
```

I get:

```
['name1
```

This removes the outer list, but also removes the last `]`.
I would like it to look like: `name1, name2`
So that i only get the names.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend using more descriptive variable names than a, b, c, d, e... The return value of `c.strip()` is a string, but `d("_")` calls it like it's a function. This should not work. Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: i've added a comment that shows where code is wrong, and also fixed another bug where you used `input` instead of `input_of_file`

Comment: You should specify how you want the output to look. Without that, I can only guess, but the most wrong-looking line is `c=str(b)` where you take a `list` of lines `b` and obtain a string representation of it (which will include the square brackets and quotes that denote the syntax for Python literals). I think this is not what you mean, but I don't know what you do mean.

Comment: Also--naming a variable `input` overwrites a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.islice` and a list comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> with open("tmp.txt") as f:
...   [line.rstrip("\n").split("_") for line in islice(f, None, None, 2)]
...
[['name1', '', '', '1 2 3 4 5'], ['name2', '', '', '1 2 3 4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your code syntax without imports:

```py
c=[]
input_of_file = '''name1___1 2 3 4 5
5=20=22=10=2=0=0=1=0=1something,something
name2___1 2 3 4
2=30=15=8=4=3=2=0=0=0;'''
a = input_of_file.split("\n")
b = a[::2] 
for item in b:
    new_item = item.split('__')
    c.append(new_item)
```

**Results**

```py
c = [['name1', '_1 2 3 4 5'], ['name2', '_1 2 3 4']]
c[0][0] = 'name1'
```